# Best way to create as many unique useState as cleanly as possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, dry

I am trying to figure out how to create as many useState as cleanly (keeping DRY principle in mind) as possible.

The problem I am trying to solve is that currently I have a menu list of items and its relative prices. The website lets the customer use a drop down menu to choose how many orders of that item he/she wants.

My question is that I know for one menu item, I can use `useState` to make something like

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
```

where the key-value pair would be `name` and `number of orders`

Now my question is: suppose I have N many menu items, how can I create as many `const [order, setOrder] = useState({})` as I need? I know I can't put useState in a for-loop so that's out of the question (?)

The below is my code I'm trying to work out:

```
export default function MenuPage() {

    // getting the menu items and prices from firebase

    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState({});
    React.useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await querySnapShot();
        result.forEach((doc) => {
            setMenuItems(doc.data());
        })
    }, []);

    return(
       
       {
            Object.keys(menuItems).map((key) => {
                return (
                    <Box
                        key={key}
                        display='flex'
                        flexDirection='row'
                        alignItems='center'
                        justifyContent='center'
                        textAlign='center'
                        borderBottom='0.5px solid black'
                        sx={{ my: 10, mx: 10 }}>
                        <Box flex={1} textAlign='center' sx={{ fontSize: '35px', }}>
                            {key}:
                        </Box>
                        <br />
                        <Box flex={1} textAlign='center' sx={{ fontSize: '25px' }}>
                            ${menuItems[key]}0
                        </Box>
                        <Box flex={1} display='flex' flexDirection='row' alignItems='center' justifyContent='end' sx={{ width: '50px' }}>
                            {/* <Typography flex={0} sx={{ mr: 5, fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontSize: '25px' }}>Order: </Typography> */}
                            <Box flex={0.5} textAlign='center'>
                                <FormControl fullWidth>
                                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Order</InputLabel>
                                    <Select
                                        value={order}
                                        name={key}
                                        label="Order"
                                        onChange={handleChange}>
                                        <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
                                    </Select>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>

                    </Box>
                );
            })
        }

    );

}
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple `setOrder`? Will the user create or edit multiple orders at the same time?

Comment: Could you share how the data array looks like? also, I doubt that there's any `data()` method within that array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes so the idea is that each line will have it's item's name, price, and a drop down menu of # of orders the user wanted to order

Comment: @FerToasted the ```data()``` method is from firebase that reads the data from cloudfirestore

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs So it sounds like you should have a single `useState()` for a list of orders rather than multiple `useState()`s for multiple orders.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice would you mind giving me an example (a high level one is fine) or somewhere I can look into more? thanks

Comment: @Code-Apprentice and also how would that work to display out to the users their current order? i.e. 1 order of A and 5 orders of B etc with one useState that holds multiple orders

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs You can do something like `const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);` Then iterate over the list of orders to render the component for each one. Personally, I would use `orders.map()` but a `for` loop can work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have an array as `response` you can:

```
const data = [
        { name: 'Foo', value: 'bar' },
        { name: 'Foo2', value: 'bar2' },
      ];

      setState(data.map({ name: 'Foo', value: 'bar' }));

      // or if no change has to be done you can set it directly into the state
      setState(data);
```